# Does #if #endif act like scope?

Tags: c, scope, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

As the title hints, my question is whether the preprocessor directives `#if` and `#endif` act like a scope? Consider the example:

```
#define foo 1
#define bar 1

#if foo
#undef bar
#endif //foo

// Is 'bar' defined or undefined here?
```

Comment: if you mean life-time scope for defines, then no it is not a scope. bar will be undefined.

Comment: How do you want to check: `if foo`, but don't have a value for that?

Comment: Please reopen. This is a different question and NOT a duplicate of the referred question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now with your example just test it and you will see it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define foo 1
#define bar 1

#if foo
#undef bar
#endif //foo

int main() {

    printf("%d", bar);

    return 0;  
}
```

Output from my compiler:

```
[Error] 'bar' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

So as you can see it's undeclared

Comment: would that be the case regardless of the compiler? I'm asking in theory.

Comment: @G.Rassovsky Yes (See: http://ideone.com/c5qFII)